# check command line arguments

Tags: bash, shell, command, line

I would like to check if the first command line argument (`$1`) has an minimum amount of 10 characters and if it is empty.

The script is called as:

```
./myscript.sh 2018-08-14
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
timestamp="$1"

# check if command line argument is empty or not present
if [ "$1" == "" ] || [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
        echo "Parameter 1 is empty"
        exit 0
elif [! "${#timestamp}" -gt 10 ]; then
        echo "Please enter at least a valid date"
        echo "Example: 2018-08-14"
        exit 0
else
        echo "THIS IS THE VALID BLOCK"
fi
```

Answer (score 17):

Well,

> ```
> if [ "$1" == "" ] || [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
>         echo "Parameter 1 is empty"
> ```

First, use `=` instead of `==`. The former is standard, the latter a bashism (though I think it's from ksh, too). Second, the logic here isn't right: if `$#` is *greater than* one, then parameter 1 probably isn't empty (it might be set to the empty string, though). Perhaps you meant `"$#" -lt 1`, though that would also imply that `"$1" = ""`. It should be enough to test `[ "$1" = "" ]`, or `[ "$#" -lt 1 ]`.

> ```
> elif [! "${#timestamp}" -gt 10 ]; then
> ```

Here, the shell would try to run a command called `[!` (literally). You need a space in between, so `[ ! "${#timestamp}" -gt 10 ]`. But that's the same as `[ "${#timestamp}" -le 10 ]`, which would also catch strings of exactly 10 characters, like `2018-08-14`.

So maybe you want `[ "${#timestamp}" -ne 10 ]`. <sub>(`!=` instead of `-ne` would also work, even though it's a string comparison.)</sub>

> ```
> if ...
>     exit 0
> ```

It's customary to return with a non-zero exit code in case of an error, so use `exit 1` in the error branches.

---

You could also use `case` or `[[ .. ]]` to pattern match the argument against the expected format, e.g.:

```
case "$1" in
    "")
        echo date is empty
        exit 1;;
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])
        echo date is ok;;
    *)
        echo "date is _not_ ok"
        exit 1;;
esac
```

That would also reject arguments like `abcdefghij`, even though it's 10 characters long.

Comment: Or `-ne` for a numeric comparison, not that it would make any difference in practice.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below script,

## Option1

```
timestamp="$1"

# check if command line argument is empty or not present
if [ -z $1 ]; then
        echo "Parameter 1 is empty"
        exit 0
elif [ "${#timestamp}" -lt 10 ]; then
        echo "Please enter at least a valid date"
        echo "Example: 2018-08-14"
        exit 0
else
        echo "THIS IS THE VALID BLOCK"
fi
```

## Option2

```
[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] && date -d "$1"
```

Comment: `[ -z $1 ]` would return true for an empty `$1` as you forgot to quote `$1`, so it would become `[ -z ]` which tests that the `-z` string is non-empty

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas what is the diff between `""` and not using it? Using it means that there is always two chars, so not empty?

Comment: Check the [top answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462528/72988) to see the exit code used for error. Moreover, you should explain the tilde as I do not see it often in bash.

Comment: @Timo, see for instance [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)